# ASP.NET Razor Pages redirect isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I have this `OnPost` method on my NewGame page:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    Name = Request.Form["Name"];
    return RedirectToRoute($"Game/{Name}");
}
```

And on the Game page I'm redirecting to:

```
@page "{name}"
```

However when I submit the NewGame page with a value in the Name field, I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
```

And I'm redirected to Game, not to Game/WhateverNameIEntered. Why is this? I set a breakpoint in my `OnPost` method and the `Name` property is getting set from the form field. How can I get the redirect to go to the proper URL?

By the way, isn't the page model `Name` property supposed to be automatically filled from the field on my form? I wonder why this isn't happening?

Comment: Do you have controller which handles `$"Game/{Name}"` route?

Comment: You normally redirect to a route you have previously mapped. It looks like you are attempting to map a route in your controller method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you can get the value Name as a parameter in your action:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(string Name)
{
    :
}
```

About the redirection you use it the wrong way. I guess Game is a Razor Page in your Pages folder. In that case you can use the following code:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(string Name)
{
    return RedirectToPage($"/Game", new { Name = Name });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why the slash before Game in the redirect path is necessary?

Comment: /Game means that we are looking for the Game.cshtml file in the pages folder, /Game/Something means that we are looking for the Something.cshtml file in the Game folder of the Pages folder, and finally ./Game means the Game.cshtml file which is located inside the folder that the current razor page is located.

Comment: Cool! So what does Game mean, without the slash?

Comment: Without the slash it is not a valid asp-page value. This will have as a result to use the current page. Using the current page happens every time that the specified asp-page is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Is Game the controller? The route by default follows this pattern

```
{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}
```

It would mean that your WhateverNameIEntered has to be an action in your controller which I doubt u have an action for every name you have.
One way to go about it is to customize the route for your needs. Something like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myGameRoute",
    template: "game/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Game", action = "Index" });
```

Answer (score -2):

I've managed to go to another razor page by using this:

HTML:

```
<button name="Users" value="Users" style="width:150px; height:150px" id="btn_Users" onclick="GoToUsers()">
    Users
 </button>
```

Script:

```
function GoToUsers() {
        fetch('http://localhost:50747/api/Users/Users')
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    window.location.href = "/Home/Users";

                }
                else {
                    alert("Failure, could not navigate");
                }
            });

    }
```

Controller:

```
Route("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly UsersContext _context;

    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ViewResult Users() => View();

    public UsersController(UsersContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //[HttpGet]
    [Route("Users")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GoToUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            //return RedirectToPage("/Users");
            return Users();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

It navigates to my Users page which resides in a folder called "Home" which resides in a folder called "Views"

However, the page is blank, even though I have a H2 tag which says welcome.